# how to obtain list of functions of a package that is installed in octave?

Tags: octave

after one installs a package, what is the command to find what functions are in that package?

for example, I have the `control` package installed. But how find help on this package such as what functions it includes and such, like with Matlab?

does one have to go to the http://octave.sourceforge.net/ web site each time to find out? Can one find this information from inside octave?

I find Matlab help much better and easier to use than octave.

Answer (score 6):

Use `pkg describe -verbose control` to get all info from the control package.

Answer (score 2):

### Octave function displaying package help

I wrote a short octave function, that solves your problem: It creates a dialogue box to display all functions in a package. After selecting one function it will display it's the help text in a message box. Just save the following octave function to a file named `pkghelp.m` and run it by typing
`pkghelp packagename`.

#### Example

The following will display the function overview for package 'io':
`pkghelp io`

#### Source Code

```matlab
% Script to display functions and help on functions for a package
function pkghelp(pkgname)

  % Get functions for this package
   des = pkg('describe','-verbose',pkgname);
   % Get first element
   des = des{1};

   if isempty(des)
     error('pkghelp:unknownPackage','Package "%s" was not found!',pkgname);
   endif
   
   % Create a dialog with functions
   pname = des.name;
   pvers = des.version;
   pdesc = des.description;
   
   % Number of categories
   ncat = numel(des.provides);
   list = cell(1,1);
   cnt=1;
   for i=1:ncat
     % Store category name
     list(cnt) = ['--(* ',des.provides{i}.category,' *)--'];
     % Number of functions
     nfunc = numel(des.provides{i}.functions);
     % Append functions in category
     list(cnt+1:cnt+nfunc) = des.provides{i}.functions(:);
     % Update counter
     cnt = cnt+1+nfunc;
   endfor

  ok=1;
  while ok==1  
    % Create dialog
    [sel, ok] = listdlg ('ListString', list,...
                     'SelectionMode', 'Single', ...
                     'ListSize',[300,600],...
                     'Name',pname,...
                     'PromptString','List of available functions');

    
    if (ok==1)
     % Selected function name
     selfun = list{sel};
     % Not a category?
     if selfun(1) ~= '-'
       % assure that package is loaded for help
       pkg('load',pkgname);
       % Get help text for selected function
       doc = help(selfun);
       % Open dialog with help text display
       msgbox(doc,[pname,'/',selfun],'help');
     endif
    endif
  endwhile
                     
endfunction
```

[octave](/questions/tagged/octave)

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux, from either within Octave or Bash (works equally), check out the package folders:

```
me@computer:/usr/share/octave/packages> ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 22. Okt 2011  .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 22. Okt 2011  ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 22. Okt 2011  openmpi_ext-1.0.1
```

Your "control" package should appear here, as a folder. Enter the folder(s) and check out the details ...

```
me@computer:/usr/share/octave/packages> cd openmpi_ext-1.0.1/
me@computer:/usr/share/octave/packages/openmpi_ext-1.0.1> ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 22. Okt 2011  .                                                                                                                                                  
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 22. Okt 2011  ..                                                                                                                                                 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  346 24. Nov 2010  allnodes                                                                                                                                           
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 22. Okt 2011  doc                                                                                                                                                
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3694 24. Nov 2010  doc-cache                                                                                                                                          
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  967 24. Nov 2010  hello2dimmat.m                                                                                                                                     
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1706 24. Nov 2010  hellocell.m                                                                                                                                        
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1359 24. Nov 2010  hellosparsemat.m                                                                                                                                   
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1711 24. Nov 2010  hellostruct.m                                                                                                                                      
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1726 24. Nov 2010  helloworld.m                                                                                                                                       
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1506 24. Nov 2010  mc_example.m                                                                                                                                       
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4721 24. Nov 2010  montecarlo.m                                                                                                                                       
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 22. Okt 2011  packinfo                                                                                                                                           
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3535 24. Nov 2010  Pi.m
```